# How to I instantiate multiple View Controllers from AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, initialization, appdelegate

[image: Storyboard]

There is a container view which holds 3 view controllers (V1, V2 and V3). I'm able to switch from A, B or C by swiping left or right. Both A or B contain their own collection view. If I tap on any cell in the collection view inside A or B, the PlayerVC (named Player in the pic above ^^) launches and a video begins to play using AVPlayer.

The problem is: Since I am using universal links the user goes straight to the playerView to play a video but when they press the done button the app crashes. The issue I beleive is because the rest on the view controllers are NOT initialized? How do I initialize the container view and the other view controllers? Or if this is not the issue please let me know what the problem is.

Here is the app delegate with some sample code. Please provide code if possible to help out!

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if let pagingViewController = window?.rootViewController as? PagingViewController {
        pagingViewController.videoPlaybackManager = videoPlaybackManager
    }
    return true
}



    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    // Other App Delegate methods.....

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

        // 1) Make sure the passed `user activity` has expected characteristics.
        guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb, let url = userActivity.webpageURL else {
            return false
        }

        // HELP: I need to get to `PlayerVC` from here?

        return true

        // If we can't do the above we default to opening the page in safari
    }
}
```

EDIT - Additional code of how I am instantiating the 3 VCs inside PagingViewController ( container View)

```
  private func setupViewControllers() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        page1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryboardIdentifiers.feedViewController.rawValue) as! FeedViewController
        page1.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        page1.delegate = self
        scrollView.addSubview(page1.view)
        addChildViewController(page1)
        page1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        // Inject dependency.
        page1.videoPlaybackManager = videoPlaybackManager

        page2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryboardIdentifiers.favoritesViewController.rawValue) as! FavoritesViewController
        page2.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        page2.delegate = self
        scrollView.addSubview(page2.view)
        addChildViewController(page2)
        page2.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        page3 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryboardIdentifiers.settingsViewController.rawValue) as! SettingsViewController
        page3.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(page3.view)
        addChildViewController(page3)
        page3.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
......
```

Comment: How are you normally initializing the Container VC?  Is that not in `didLaunchWithOptions`?

Comment: Hey I just added more code to my example showing how its done. Thanks

Comment: Actually the ContainerVC is being initialized through storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with `UIPageViewController`, to set the proper child `UIViewController` you can:

```
// In PagingViewController
func loadChildViewControllerFromUniversalLink(myParameter: Bool) {
    // The condition you need to satisfied in order to present
    // the correct child view controller
    if  myParameter { // is satisfied
        let universalLinkVc = MyChildViewController() // load your VC here
        let direction : UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection = .forward // or .reverse, as you wish
        self.setViewControllers([universalLinkVc], direction: direction, animated: animated, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And then in your `AppDelegate`'s `application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool`:

```
myPagingViewControllerInstance.loadChildViewControllerFromUniversalLink(true)
```

Comment: Hello Felipe. I am not using UIPageViewController but instead am using a VC called PagingViewController which acts a a Container view for V1, V2 and V3. I then instantiate all of the 3 Vc there. Please take a look at the additional code I added and if possible modify your code accordingly. Thanks for the help!!